# htaccess https rewrite issue when trying to login to cmsms

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having some issues with my rewrite rules since moving to a new server. Our previous server was Apache 2.2.13 with PHP 5.2.11, the new server is Apache 2.2.25 with PHP 5.4.18.

I am ensuring all traffic is transferred to www. and https

The redirects work fine for users, but when I try to login to cmsms, I enter my username and password and click login and the page refreshes, clearing the username and password boxes rather than logging into admin. I can login if I remove the following from the htaccess file.

This is what is in the htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I had some issues with the php.ini that I had transferred across so replaced it with this, maybe I need more?:

```
register_globals = off
date.timezone = Europe/London
output_buffering = 1
;zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube.so
post_max_size = 20M
memory_limit = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
max_execution_time = 120
expose_php = off
session.save_path = /tmp
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED?????????????????
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So, users can login via frontend, but you cannot login via backend (as I can understand from your question), right?

Comment: No, users can see the content which has been created, but I cannot login to the admin area to edit the content.

Comment: @user2657534 what is the URL to the admin? I mean from your example is the URL something like admin/index.php? or admin/home? or does it have anything that contains home or index.php? As for the version of your PHP and apache server that should not give you any impact on the code unless it really used `register_globals` which since PHP 5 I hardly see anyone using so check your PHP files and see if they use `$_GET` or `$_POST` around if they do you're mostly fine having it turned off.

Comment: If I remove: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] I can login, so it doesnt seem that the canonical url part is causing any issue. energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/admin is the login url.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my point of view, of course, your "problem" is caused by:

- (updated) apache rewrite module in new version of apache (what is normal for apache updates anyway) and of course, IF your script have been working fine at - previous server.

You might give it a try by removing (or playing around with) these lines away, for a start at least;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

assuming that your php script supports upcoming URI changes after this. If that will work, get you logged in (and your users will have problems), deal is to write those lines back and a codework for your login panel to obey new rewrite rules.

Anyway I would not recommend to mess up php.ini until this apache problem is solved up.

Note: This kind of your problem and behavior was/is normal for register globals also, but that function is completely removed starting from php 5.4.0 and that kind of an "option" was/is used in quite old scripts.